# jitsi meet android sdk configuation issue

Tags: android, sdk, jitsi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B23Ip.png)

I AM NOT ABLE TO LOAD MY URL FOR JITSI IN ANDROID i.e.

```
jitsiView.loadURL("http://example.org/aayush");
```

BUT IT LOADs DEFAULT JITSI URL IN ANDROID FOR TEST i.e.

```
view.loadURL("https://meet.jit.si/Test123");
```

it shows the error -> E/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to load config from 
https://example.org/config.js?room=aayush'

please check the attached image for details.

Comment: please help i am badly stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a ssl certificate issue .. certificate was not mapped with the IP. Issue resolved.